# cpp multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, boost-multi-array

I want to store theses string vectors as a 4 dimensional vector. It has been three days that I am searching and I can not decide wether use multidimensional vector,boost multi array ,array of struct ,...
I am so new to cpp and they  are so confusing.

```
vector < string >ID;
vector < string > firstName;
vector < string > lastName;
vector < string > address;
vector<vector<vector<vector<string> >>> person ;
```

what should I do for populating person ?

Comment: What about `class person { /*...*/ };`

Comment: A multi-dimension vector is required if for instance you have multiple firstnames for an id and multiple lastnames for a firstname and multiple addresses for each lastname. If you just want to store the details of a person, then @hansmaad's suggestion is most suitable.

Comment: Ok... so what the actual problem is? You want us to decide for you, which data structure should you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, there is no point in creating multidimensional array. I'd rather try:

```
class Person
{
public:
    string Id;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string address;
};

(...)

vector<Person> People;

// Adding
Person p;
p.Id = "1234";
People.push_back(p);

// Count
std::cout << "Currently you have " << People.size() << " people in the database";

// Access
Person p1 = People[0];
```

---

**Edit:** In response to comments

It's quite tough to answer the question without some specifics about your problem. From what little I know about it, I'd probably go into multi-class version:

```
class Id
{
public:
    int Value;
    std::vector<FirstName> Names;
}

class FirstName
{
public:
    string Value;
    std::vector<SecondName> SecondNames;
}

class SecondName
{
public:
    string Value;
    std::vector<Address> Addresses;
}

class Address
{
public:
    string Value;
}
```

Comment: I have multiple lastnames

Comment: @user1876128 You mean, that a single person can have multiple lastnames?

Comment: yes I just simplified the question in real case my variables are different and can have different values

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @hansmaad

The following would be a simpler and better implementation(compared to mulch-dimensional vectors) for storing personal details in your program.

Define a person as:

```
struct person {
    std::string id;
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    std::string address;
};
```

And define your `vector` as:

```
std::vector< person > people;
```

Answer (score 0):

structure of arrays may be ! Or for a better readable and changeable code use a class